# Contar regitros a partir de tres tablas con PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy trabajando en una app de jugadoras de hockey. Donde deben crear un equipo de práctica y a la vez estar seleccionadas para ese equipo.

Las tablas:

Tabla perfil (perfil de las jugadoras)

```
+----+--------+-----------+
| id | nombre | posicion  |
+----+--------+-----------+
| 1  | Laura  | Delantera |
| 2  | Anna   | Defensa   |
| 3  | Mica   | Arquera   |
| 4  | Zoe    | Delantera |
+----+--------+-----------+
```

Tabla equipo (equipo de práctica, lo debe crear la capitana del equipo)

```
+----------+--------+-----------+-------------+
| idequipo | userid | nombre    |  categoria  |
+----------+--------+-----------+-------------+
|    1     |   1    | Equipo A  |    7        |
|    2     |   3    | Equipo B  |    11       |
|    3     |   2    | Equipo C  |    18       |
+----------+--------+-----------+-------------+
```

Tabla Selección (selección de jugadoras y equipo)

```
+----------+------------+----------+
| idselec  | jugadoraid | equipoid |
+----------+------------+----------+
|    1     |     1      |     3    |
|    2     |     3      |     3    |
|    3     |     2      |     1    |
+----------+------------+----------+


<?php

$app = new Main(); // Objeto Main, extiende la conexión de la base de datos

$postsql = $app->connect()->query("SELECT * FROM seleccion INNER JOIN perfil ON perfil.id = seleccion.jugadoraid INNER JOIN equipo ON equipo.idequipo = seleccion.equipoid WHERE idequipo = 3");
$lista = $postsql->fetchAll();

?>
```

Lo que trato de hacer es contar las jugadoras de cada equipo para saber cuantas jugadoras faltan para completar un equipo de práctica que puede ser de 7, 9, 11 o 18 jugadoras, sumando a la capitana que fue la creadora del equipo.

En la consulta quise utilizar la `COUNT()`, pero al no tener un total, no sé como implementarlo. La categoría en la tabla `equipo` hace referencia a la cantidad de jugadoras que debe haber en el partido de práctica, si son 11, significa que se necesitan 22 para completar la práctica.

Espero se entienda la idea y agradezco la ayuda de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me parece entender que necesitas algo como esto:

```
SELECT idequipo,nombre,
  categoria-IFNULL(n,0) jugadoras_faltantes
  FROM (
    SELECT equipoid idequipo,COUNT(*) n
      FROM seleccion
      GROUP BY 1  
  ) c1 RIGHT JOIN equipo USING(idequipo);
```

Lo de la capitana no termina de quedarme claro, pero entiendo que con sumar o restar uno ya te cuadre con el resultado que esperas.

Por cierto, vendría bien que modificaras la pregunta incorporando el resultado que esperas de tu consulta. Yo obtengo esto, espero que sea lo que buscabas:

```
+----------+----------+---------------------+
| idequipo | nombre   | jugadoras_faltantes |
+----------+----------+---------------------+
|        1 | Equipo A |                   6 |
|        2 | Equipo B |                  11 |
|        3 | Equipo C |                  16 |
+----------+----------+---------------------+
```

Así como el dataset en formato SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE perfil(
  id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  nombre varchar(31),
  posicion varchar(31)
  );
INSERT INTO perfil (id, nombre, posicion) VALUES
('1','Laura','Delantera'),
('2','Anna ','Defensa'),
('3','Mica ','Arquera'),
('4','Zoe  ','Delantera');
CREATE TABLE equipo(
  idequipo int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  userid int,
  nombre varchar(31),
  categoria int
  );
INSERT INTO equipo (idequipo, userid, nombre, categoria) VALUES
('1','1','Equipo A','7'),
('2','3','Equipo B','11'),
('3','2','Equipo C','18');
CREATE TABLE seleccion(
  idselec int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  jugadoraid int,
  equipoid int
  );
INSERT INTO seleccion (idselec, jugadoraid, equipoid) VALUES
('1','1','3'),
('2','3','3'),
('3','2','1');
```

Espero que te haya resultado útil. Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios.

Comment: Muchas gracias David!